# Adjacency matrices needed for common graphs

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

I'm making a program which requires adjacency matrices of undirected graphs.  In particular, I'd like the adjacency matrices for the graphs in this wiki link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_automorphism

Some of these graphs are big so I do not want to sit around all day typing in all the matrices.  Can someone please refer me to either a program or book where I can find such adjacency matrices?

Thanks in advance!  :)

Comment: You can get adjacency matrices for many interesting graphs from Mathematica, for example, or various online sources. Where have you looked? If you told us what effort *you* have made, we can avoid giving you information that is not useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Any math software that includes graph theory ought to have commands to generate common graphs and a command to take the adjacency matrix of any graph.  Mathematica is one example.

Some of them you can get from Wolfram Alpha ([example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=petersen%20graph%20adjacency%20matrix)).

Comment: There are also some databases available, such as House of Graphs: http://hog.grinvin.org/StartNewSearch.action